# console.log output to document instead of console

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, console

I have an extremely simple html file that only consists of the following:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script defer src="./bundle_ACTUAL.js"></script>
    </head>
</html>
```

When `./bundle_ACTUAL.js` is run, I get the output in the Chrome Console

Is there a way to redirect that output of `./bundle_ACTUAL.js` to actually print in the document?

Answer (score 1):

You can override `console.log`'s default behavior to instead write to the `document`:

```js
console.log = function(e){ document.write(e) }

console.log("Hello World!")
```

Or alternatively, just replace every occurrence of `console.log` with `document.write`:

```js
document.write("Hello World!")
```

Comment: Thank you, but where should I put these 2 lines of code? In the html file? Or in ./bundle_ACTUAL.js?

Comment: @user3438258 You should put it on the first line of `./bundle_ACTUAL.js`

Comment: So, I did what you suggested and now the page is displaying "'Hello World."  The issue is that when I use "html = urlopen(req).read()" with python to get the webpage content, I do not get "hello world", but rather "'<html>\r\n    <head>\r\n        <script defer src="./bundle_ACTUAL.js"></script>\r\n    </head>\r\n</html>'". Any way around that?

Comment: @user3438258 What does `urlopen(req).read()` return?

Comment: It literally returns a string "b'<html>\r\n    <head>\r\n        <script defer src="./bundle_ACTUAL.js"></script>\r\n    </head>\r\n</html>'" which is the source code of the original html file, and not the output of bundle_ACTUAL.js.

Comment: @user3438258 Can you share the complete code of `bundle_ACTUAL.js`?

Comment: If I look at the chrome console, it returns bundle_ACTUAL.js:32237 
        
       Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened.
console.log @ bundle_ACTUAL.js:32237

Comment: I apologize, I  cannot-- it loads a complicated API output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238378/discussion-between-spectric-and-user3438258).